# Karush-Kuhn-Tucker system

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have the following problem

> Consider the problem to find the minimizer of $f(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j}-a_{j})^{2}$, $a_{j}\in \mathbb{R}$, $j=1,2,\dots, n$, $\hspace{2mm}$ restricted to  $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{2}\leq 1,\hspace{3mm}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}= 0 $.

The  KKT system is

1. $L_{x_{j}}(x,\mu_{1},\mu_{2})=2(x_{j}-a_{j})+\lambda +2\mu 
   x_{j}=0\hspace{4mm}\text{para}\hspace{2mm}j=1,2,\cdots, n$;

2.$\mu\geq 0$;

3.$\mu\left[\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{2}-1\right]=0$;

4.$\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}= 0$;

5. $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{2}-1\leq 0$;

We will consider cases

a. If $\mu=0$, then in 1.  we have  $x_{j}=\frac{2a_{j}-\lambda}{2}$, put this value in  4. We have $\lambda= \frac{2}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}$, Thus $x_{j}= a_{j}-\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}$. But in this point I'm stuck, since I don't know how to verify that the 5. is true or false.

b.  If $\mu \neq 0$, the only that I have is that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{2}-1=0$ but I'm not to sure how use this fact.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sum over the $x_j$ in 1. and find $\lambda$. Then, solve for $x_j$, square that, sum and use the equality for the $x_j^2$, this will lead to a value for $\mu$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $\mu\ne0$, and summing 1. over $i=1,\ldots,n$ yields

$$\lambda=\dfrac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i=2\bar{a},$$

where $\bar a:=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ is the mean value of the sequence $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ and where we have used 4.

Now, from 1., again, we have that

$$(1+\mu)x_j=a_j-\bar{a}.$$

Squaring and summing yields

$$(1+\mu)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_j-\bar{a})^2,$$

where we have used 5., which is an equality here. Let $V(a)=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_j-\bar{a})^2/n$ which is the variance of the sequence $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$. Then, we have that

$$(1+\mu)^2=nV(a)$$

and

$$\mu=(nV(a))^{1/2}-1.$$

This finally yields

$$x_j=\dfrac{a_j-\bar{a}}{(nV(a))^{1/2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks! KBS for the answer. The case a. There is not need to consider since the $f(x)=\|x-a\|^{2}$ is strongly convex, and the strongly convex functions the minimizer is unique. rigth? but want to prove that 5. in the case a. is false. How can I to do it? Thanks again.

Comment: @Zacarias89. Whether you are in case a. or b. will depend on the values of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. Check what are the conditions for which 5. is a strict inequality.

Comment: Thanks.  that's exactly what I can't do. Sorry if I'm asking nonsense, but I want to learn.

Comment: @Zacarias89. Please update your question with your attempts.